# printing localVariable keeps giving error

Tags: javascript, variables, global-variables, local-variables

console.log(localVariable keeps giving a reference error

```
var globalVariable = "A"; // a global variable
        function testScope1() {
        var localVariable = "B"; // a local variable
        
        
        }

        console.log(globalVariable); // A
        console.log(localVariable); // ReferenceError
```

Comment: The local variable is not visible outside the function it's declared in.

Comment: okay, so how do i print it out then....the code has to be in the function?

Comment: Either return it or print it from inside the function. In any case, you have to actually run the function to even get the variable declared.